# Do the derivation of the liar paradox, and the ontological argument, involve the same mistake?

Tags: paradox, ontological-argument

Suppose you introduced the sentence, "This sentence implies a contradiction." Now, on its face, that sentence *doesn't* seem to imply *anything* (maybe not even itself) as such.

Reworked: "This sentence's being true would imply a contradiction." Or even: "This sentence's being *false* would imply a contradiction." At any rate, it seems as if, for standard deductions of the liar paradox itself to go through, it should be possible to introduce, "This sentence implies a contradiction," as its equivalent. Yet such an introduction *doesn't* go through; ergo...

More generally: consider, "An existent *X* doesn't exist." This isn't absolutely self-contradictory (just rephrase it as, "An existent *X* is not to be found," say). Kant surmises that it is nonsensical to speak of an existence such that its negation would imply a contradiction. Yet then if the intuitive deduction of the liar paradox were valid,  it seems as if we should be able to define a sentence into existence, and into an existence such that it implies a contradiction: "There exists a sentence, this sentence, such that if this sentence exists, then a contradiction obtains."

A weird counterpart to the ontological argument, then, though? So, whatever is wrong with "the" ontological argument (or various formulations of it, at least) is similarly wrong with many derivations of the liar paradox? (I could see, for example, saying that we can derive that the liar sentence is true and false, yet not that its being true and false is a contradiction. "*B*: *A*&~*A*, therefore *B* is contradictory," seems possible to suppress given the way in which we use "is false" in the formulation of the liar sentence in the first place.)

***A sketch of a "rigorous" presentation***

1. If the derivation of the liar paradox (by assigning truth or falsity to the liar sentence "from the outside") were not incorrect on some level, then it would be possible to define something as existing and implying a contradiction by its existence. (I don't mean a linguistic contradiction; I mean an incompatible pair of possible facts supposedly being real.)
2. But that is like trying to define a being into existence at all, i.e. not allowed (as analysis of the ontological argument shows).
3. Defining something into existence is not possible, because, "The existent *X* doesn't exist," is not actually contradictory. It *sounds* contradictory, but the main thing is that the meaning of "existent" is not coincident with the meaning of "exists," here, no matter what the speaker otherwise intends (since putting the one term in adjective position and the other in predicate position result in different, if similar, concepts of existence).
4. To prove that a sentence contradicts another sentence, one must invoke relations between the sentences. The bare assertion that some sentence generates a contradiction lacks a basis for being true, since only one (indeterminate) sentence is under consideration. This is akin to how something cannot be determinately said to exist by having a property that the thing might be stipulated to have, a property of "existing." Instead, existing "syntactically" differs from having properties, and so too do truth/falsity operations on sentences stand apart from the properties inside propositions.
5. Accordingly, just as, "An existent *X* doesn't exist," is not actually self-contradictory, neither is, "It is true that this sentence is false," etc.

Comment: Is there some relevance to using "this sentence implies a contradiction" rather than "this sentence is false"? Letting ≡ stand for "is defined as", the usual liar paradox is P≡¬P. You are using P≡(∃Q)(P→Q)∧(P→¬Q). Why?

Comment: I also don't get why you find this remarkable: "it seems as if we should be able to define a sentence into existence, and into an existence such that it implies a contradiction". It seem's perfectly natural to be able to do that. In fact, it would be remarkable if we couldn't.

Comment: Finally, I'm not seeing the connection to the Ontological Argument. Maybe it would help if you would show the logical form you are assuming for both the Ontological Argument and for the Liar.

Comment: @DavidGudeman, the idea is that if the quantifier-free liar sentence is "admissible," then a quantified version of it should be too, but once the quantified version is spelled out, it looks like the original sentence has some sort of "design error" in it, that undermines the validity of attempts to derive a paradox from the liar sentence. Now, the liar sentence is meant to be stipulated into existence, and it supposedly generates a contradiction thereby, albeit in an even more deviant way than when the problem arises with the ontological argument.

Comment: The liar sentence constantly probes similar questions such as "is this sentence so written true, deep and worth study?" "Is this sentence in my mind given from heaven?" "What's the difference between this sentence is false and that sentence is true?" Thus liar is like a mirror from which we derive as if it cannot be made sense at all to be derived, ergo its derivation is not derivation, we couldn't describe it as if it's describable, like the famous profound ancient naming paradox from the East which says "white horse is not horse"...